# How does oracle server deal with instance when the network connection is lost

Tags: oracle, connection

The client I used to connect to the oracle server is PL/SQL developper.

By mistask,i executed an anonymous PL/SQL block within a loop that would forever running,
so i pressed break button and waited for more than 1 hour.

but the block was still running while the client shows tip "script cancelled".then i cutted off the net connection .

So my question is Why the Block is still running after "script cancelled" 
and how would the server deal with my instance when then net connection is lost.

Answer (score 2):

This session has to be killed by the dba. If the loop is ever reaching a normal termination, the transaction will be rolled back. The reason for the rollback is that the server sees that the client has gone and won't get a commit, unless it was coded.
If the loop has waits in it, for example because IO has to be done, or an other package has to be called, it will terminate.

Comment: And by what you mean,the server would do nothing about the lost session automatically, until the dba kill it?

Comment: If the server has time to look around, it will cleanup the session. If not, because it is in a tight loop, the dba has to kill it, most of the times by killing the background process.

Comment: thank you again,and soory for my english as no native speaker.

Comment: you are welcome, for some reason, my blog is called 'From Errors We learn' .... :-)

Comment: yes,of course.but i'm sorry that vote up your answer requires 15 reputation, which i don't really have. is there any other thing i can do for your favor?

Comment: oh.and by the way,blogspot.com is blocked from china internet(maybe intranet is more appropriate..) for some reason, maybe i could manage to visit your blog and learn something sometimes latter,Thank you.